# Cache XML API Response in php server side caching

Tags: php, xml, api, caching, post

Is it possible to cache the response from a POST request to a XML API? I want to do this without having to create actual files on my server. I was told this is possible but Ive been unsuccessful.

Essentially.. I want to check if that call was already made, if so..pull that data, if not do the API call and save for future use.

Comment: Hi, what have you tried so far? Any code examples? Could you try to follow http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

To do this without files you would need to store the call and the result in a database.  It is probably the best way to do it anyway.  I have done this with google geolocation API because there are limits on how many requests you can do per day.

So I would just store the request (i.e. a zip code like 37206) and the result from google.  Then the next time 37206 was requested I would just return the result stored in my database.

Further, to prevent something like a zip code lat/lon change I would store the date at which the result was stored and after say a year, I would use a cron to remove it.